# Why is my icon slightly higher than other ones?

Tags: c#, icons

In my taskbar, the icon of my program is *slightly* higher than other programs:

[image]

Mine is the orange triangle, the furthest one on the left.

All the other icons are lined up perfectly, but my program is a *wee bit* higher than them.

This does this with every icon I've tried and both when I'm debugging it and just running it normally (as in, not started with visual studio).

The program's coded in C#.

Comment: What dimensions are your icon? The others may be slightly larger, and have padding around them, giving the effect you're seeing.

Comment: I believe it's 32x32. I don't have any application capable of opening it to check however.

Comment: Perhaps you could attach the icon? If I had to guess there is probably blank space at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image is not higher it just doesn't fill the entire area.

[image: Not higher]